# How to Post using JSON and JQuery from a form?

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I'm using jQuery and the CloudKit/Tokyo Cabinet backend from an HTML page. All calls are REST/JSON so the server needs JSON data posted. How do I turn the form into JSON and post it? JQuery seems to have a type for JSON return values but not to send JSON.

Any ideas? IS it different if it's cross domain?

Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can use: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

See also: [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the toJSON plugin mentioned on the [jQuery plugin page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins).